# Using angular to turn a multi-dimensional array into a multi level list using php and usort

Tags: php

I have been working on this a while. I see multi-level arrays in php are not that easy. Here is my code:

```
Array
(
[0]=array(
   "level"=>'Level1',
   "id"=>1,
   "title"=>"Home",
   "order"=>"0"
    );
[1]=array(
    "level"=>'Level1',
    "id"=>"355",
    "title"=>"About Us", 
    "order"=>"21"
  );
 [2]=array(
    "level"=>'Level1',
    "id"=>"10",
    "title"=>"Test",
    "order"=>"58"
 );
[3]=array(
    "level"=>'Level2',
    "id"=>13,
    "title"=>"Our Team",
    "order"=>"11",
    "parent_id"=>"355"
 );
  [4]=array(
    "level"=>'Level2',
    "id"=>12,
    "title"=>"The In Joke",
    "order"=>"12",
    "parent_id"=>"355"
  );
  [5]=array(
    "level"=>'Level2',
    "id"=>11,
    "title"=>"Our History",
    "order"=>"13",
    "parent_id"=>"355"
  ));
> 



   1-Home
   2-about us
   3-Our Team
   4-The In Joke
   5-Our History
   6-Test
```

i have multi-level parent child array and need to sort according to about result did not understand how i can use `usort()`.

Comment: Can we see your code (instead of just the result)?

Answer (score 0):

To use `usort()` to sort your array, you need to write a custom sort function. Because you want to look at the `$array['title']` value for the comparison, you would use this array index in your comparison function:

```
$array = array(
    array(
       "level"=>'Level1',
       "id"=>1,
       "title"=>"Home",
       "order"=>"0"
    ),
    // your additional multidimensional array values...
);

// function for `usort()` - $a and $b are both arrays, you can look at their values for sorting
function compare($a, $b){
    // If the values are the same, return 0
    if ($a['title'] == $b['title']) return 0;
    // if the title of $a is less than $b return -1, otherwise 1
    return ($a['title'] < $b['title']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, 'compare');
```